# if/else with heredoc not behaving as expected

Tags: php, heredoc

I am using heredoc to build a simple text email, but for some reason I am getting strange results around my if/else conditional:

```
<?php 
$message = <<<EOD
Hi Username
EOD;

echo $message.'<hr>';

if(true) {
    $message .= <<<EOD
Thanks for logging in
EOD;                    
} else {
    $message .= <<<EOD
Thanks for signing up.  
EOD;
}       

echo $message.'<hr>';   

$message .= <<<EOD
Good Bye                    
EOD;
echo '<pre>'.$message.'</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Hi UsernameThanks for logging in
EOD;                    
} else {
    Hi Username .= <<<EOD
Thanks for signing up.  Good Bye
```

For some reason it's outputting my PHP - if I change true to false I just get `Hi UsernameGood Bye` which is even more puzzling.

Comment: it's just my opinion but i think this is not a very good use of heredoc, you will be better off using double quotes

Comment: Is everything wrapped in PHP tags? Is what you show the browser source code?

Comment: Is the `EOD;` definitely on the first character column of the file? It must not be indented.

Comment: Sorry I have updated my question, yes I am using php tags and yes I am looking at the exact output as opposed to the rendered HTML

Comment: @ibu I have shortened the lines for convenience in this question

Comment: @Dumhamzz: Check your editor, it might have a function to remove whitespaces at the end of each line. Run that one, save the file and test again ;) - See [Konerak's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187226/if-else-with-heredoc-not-behaving-as-expected/7187307#7187307).

Comment: Or else `s/\s+$//g` works too ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `EOD;` should be ALL that is present on the line. Only those 4 characters.

You did fine for the first, third and fourth `EOD;`, but the second `EOD;` has whitespace behind the EOD;. Select the code (or view in hexedit or showing whitespace) to see:

```
$message = <<<EOD
Hi Username
EOD;

echo $message.'<hr>';

if(true) {
    $message .= <<<EOD
Thanks for logging in
EOD;                    
} else {
    $message .= <<<EOD
Thanks for signing up.  
EOD;
}       

echo $message.'<hr>';   

$message .= <<<EOD
Good Bye                    
EOD;
echo $message;
```

Image clarification:

[image: http://img803.imageshack.us/img803/826/whitespaceheredoc.png]

This causes everything between the second EOD and the third EOD to be considered as the here-document :)

If you would have used EOD1, EOD2, EOD3 and EOD4, you'd have gotten the warning 'EOD2 not found' or something along those lines.
You're not the first to encounter this error, the [PHP HereDoc Manualpage](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) even shows a warning (with whitespace before the heredoc endmarker). What hakre added is indeed correct, as also explained on the manpage: 'possibly' a semicolon.

Comment: I think it's possible to omit `;` for the end-marker. But the explanation is correct, +1.